# Java - How to find students with their highest marks writing a method in a Student class?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, methods

I'm a beginner in java and got stuck in one task. I will be very thankful if anyone could help me. I have a class Student with these attributes - name, chemistry mark, mathematics mark and physics mark. In the Main class I have created an ArrayList with several students. My task is to find students (their names) with the highest chemistry mark among all students, highest mathematics and highest physics mark among all students. I did this in the Main class main method but the problem is that I have to write this in the Student's class and at this point I fail to do it.

Here's my code:

```
public class Student {

    protected String name;
    private int chemistry;
    private int mathematics;
    private int physics;


    public Student(String name, int chemistry, int mathematics, int physics) {
        this.name = name;
        this.chemistry = chemistry;
        this.mathematics = mathematics;
        this.physics = physics;
    }

    public int getChemistry() {
        return chemistry;
    }

    public void setChemistry(int chemistry) {
        this.chemistry = chemistry;
    }

    public int getMathematics() {
        return mathematics;
    }

    public void setMathematics(int mathematics) {
        this.mathematics = mathematics;
    }

    public int getPhysics() {
        return physics;
    }

    public void setPhysics(int physics) {
        this.physics = physics;
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Student tom = new Student("Tom", 7, 6, 4);
        Student rome = new Student("Rome", 9, 5, 8);
        Student jack = new Student("Jack", 6, 9, 8);
        Student simon = new Student("Simon", 10, 8, 5);
        Student darek = new Student("Darek", 10, 9, 8);

        ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

        students.add(tom);
        students.add(rome);
        students.add(jack);
        students.add(simon);
        students.add(darek);


        System.out.println("Student(s) with the highest Chemistry grade among all students:");

        int max = 0;
        String names = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
            if (max == students.get(i).getChemistry()) { 
                names += ", " + students.get(i).name;
            } else if (max < students.get(i).getChemistry()) {
                       max = students.get(i).getChemistry(); 
                       names = students.get(i).name; 
            }
        }
        System.out.println(names);


        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Student(s) with the highest Mathematics grade among all students:");

        max = 0;
        names = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
            if (max == students.get(i).getMathematics()) {
                names += ", " + students.get(i).name;
            } else if (max < students.get(i).getMathematics()) {
                       max = students.get(i).getMathematics();
                       names = students.get(i).name; 
            }
        }
        System.out.println(names);


        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Student(s) with the highest Physics grade among all students:");


        max = 0;
        names = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
            if (max == students.get(i).getPhysics()) {
                names += ", " + students.get(i).name;
            } else if (max < students.get(i).getPhysics()) {
                       max = students.get(i).getPhysics();
                       names = students.get(i).name; 
            }
        }
        System.out.println(names);

    }
}
```

I tried to write a similar method in the Student class:

```
public int bestOfChemistry(int max, String names) {
        if (max == chemistry) {
            names += ", " + name;   
        } else if (max < chemistry) {
            max = chemistry;
            names = name;
        }
        return max;
    }
```

But when I'm trying to use this method in the Main class I can only obtain the maximum grade. I know, because I only returned it in the method bestOfChemistry(..), but I don't know how to get their names too:

```
int max = 0;
String names = null;
for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
            max = students.get(i).bestOfChemistry(max, names);
        }
        System.out.println(max);
```

I don't know also how to write a one method for these three lessons that to avoid several identical methods.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't make methods that reference multiple objects in a class that represents a single object, it doesn't make sense, semantically.

EDIT: Since you're not allowed to do it in the main class, you can add a new class whose function is to search for the best students. I'll name it "StudentsFinder", for example. It looks like this:

```java
class StudentsFinder {

    private final ArrayList<Student> students;
    private ArrayList<String> bestStudents;

    StudentsFinder(ArrayList<Student> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }

    ArrayList<String> getBestChemistryStudents() {
        bestStudents = new ArrayList<>();
        int maxChemistryGrade = 0;
        //We look for the best grade first.
        for (Student student : students) {
            if (student.getChemistry() > maxChemistryGrade) {
                maxChemistryGrade = student.getChemistry();
            }
        }
        //Now we can add those students with the best grade in the array
        for (Student student : students) {
            if (student.getChemistry() == maxChemistryGrade) {
                bestStudents.add(student.getName());
            }
        }
        //And we return the results
        return bestStudents;
    }
    //The following methods do the same thing but with math and physics grades, respectively 
    ArrayList<String> getBestMathStudents() {
        bestStudents = new ArrayList<>();
        int maxMathGrade = 0;
        for (Student student : students) {
            if (student.getMathematics() > maxMathGrade) {
                maxMathGrade = student.getMathematics();
            }
        }
        for (Student student : students) {
            if (student.getMathematics() == maxMathGrade) {
                bestStudents.add(student.getName());
            }
        }
        return bestStudents;
    }

    ArrayList<String> getBestPhysicsStudents() {
        bestStudents = new ArrayList<>();
        int maxPhysicsGrade = 0;
        for (Student student : students) {
            if (student.getPhysics() > maxPhysicsGrade) {
                maxPhysicsGrade = student.getPhysics();
            }
        }
        for (Student student : students) {
            if (student.getPhysics() == maxPhysicsGrade) {
                bestStudents.add(student.getName());
            }
        }
        return bestStudents;
    }
}
```

In the Student class you're going to need a getter for the name:

```java
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

Then, you can add a new StudentsFinder instance in the main class, you pass it the students array in the constructor, and call each method:

```java
StudentsFinder finder = new StudentsFinder(students);

System.out.println("Student(s) with the highest Chemistry grade among all students:");
System.out.println(finder.getBestChemistryStudents());

System.out.println("Student(s) with the highest Mathematics grade among all students:");
System.out.println(finder.getBestMathStudents());

System.out.println("Student(s) with the highest Physics grade among all students:");
System.out.println(finder.getBestPhysicsStudents());
```

Note that we can pass the result directly to the `println()` method:

```java
System.out.println(finder.getBestChemistryStudents());
```

...because it automatically calls `toString()` in the `ArrayList`, whose implementation is inherited from `AbstractCollection` class. It prints all values in `[value1, value2, ..., valueN]` format.

Comment: Didn't he ask how to implement it in the Student class? I think he already found a way to achieve this in `main()`

Comment: Thank you, it is another great way to find the best chemistry students with Arraylist. But my task is to write highest mark calculations in the Student or in another class, but not in the main. It's not my decision so I have to. Perhaps you know how your code would look not in the main class?

Comment: @stavla I edited my answer, check it out. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

You have some design issues I guess. Class is a blueprint on which you will initialize an object, in this case, each Student object is a separate student which attributes name, chemistry, physics, mathematics. That does not make sense to have a method in a Student class to give you the list of student names with the highest marks. So, my suggestion is to have a Classroom, Course or maybe School class which will have an attribute such as a list of students. In that class, the function to get the list of students who got the highest marks makes sense as for each Classroom lets say you can find it. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Could you please comment when you mark it as a not useful answer.

Comment: I upvote your answer, since it really makes sense unlike the other one

Comment: This is a very logical remark, thank you. Should my class Classroom extend Students' class or it should be an independent class? Also, I don't know what syntax should be of the highest grade method in the new class that I could call it from the Main.

Comment: Classroom class may have ArrayList<Student> where Student is the class that you have written. Extends means you are creating a subclass based on the base class. Student class is not a base class for Classroom, but e.g. Person class may be a superclass for Student class, so Student can extend from Person class. By saying syntax of the method you mean its signature ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the code. I'm not sure how to write a method to find students with the highest grades in the class Classroom. I think it should be the similar loops like I have wrote in the Main class?

Answer (score 1):

```
public enum Subject{
    CHEMISTRY,
    MATH,
    PHYSICS;
}


public String findNameOfTheBest(List<Student> students, Subject subject){
    switch(subject){
        case CHEMISTRY:
            return students.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getChemistry).reversed()).findFirst().map(Student::getName).get();
        case MATH:
            return students.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getMathematics).reversed()).findFirst().map(Student::getName).get();
        case PHYSICS:
            return students.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getPhysics).reversed()).findFirst().map(Student::getName).get();
        default:
            throw new Exception("unknown subject type");
    }
}
```

Simply call this method with a different subject type and assign the return value to a variable. A short explanation: It orders each student object in the list by one of its properties, which could be chemistry, mathematics or physics depending on which Subject you passed in, (for example Subject.CHEMISTRY). It then reverses the ordering so that the highest mark is at the very beginning of the list. Then it calls findFirst() which returns an Optional. On this Optional a map method is called, which basically converts the element from Student object to its property 'name'.

EDIT: Heres the adjusted method that takes in account the possibility of multiple students with the highest grade.

```
public List<String> findNameOfTheBest(List<Student> students, Subject subject){
    switch(subject){
        case CHEMISTRY:
            int highestMark = students.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getChemistry)).get();
            return students.stream().filter(student -> student.getChemistry == highestMark).map(Student::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
        case MATH:
            int highestMark = students.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getMathematics)).get();
            return students.stream().filter(student -> student.getMathematics == highestMark).map(Student::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
        case PHYSICS:
            int highestMark = students.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getPhysics)).get();
            return students.stream().filter(student -> student.getPhysics == highestMark).map(Student::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
        default:
            throw new Exception("unknown subject type");
    }
}
```

Comment: And what if there are two or more students with the highest subject marks, it returns only one student of them?

Comment: @stavla i've included a new method that can return a list of names

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to do it:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student tom = new Student("Tom", 7, 6, 4);
        Student rome = new Student("Rome", 9, 5, 8);
        Student jack = new Student("Jack", 6, 9, 8);
        Student simon = new Student("Simon", 10, 8, 5);
        Student darek = new Student("Darek", 10, 9, 8);
        derek.bestChem();
        derek.bestPhys();
        derek.bestMath();
}
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int chemistry;
    private int mathematics;
    private int physics;
    public static ArrayList<Student> students= new ArrayList<Student>();

    public Student(String name, int chemistry, int mathematics, int physics) {
        this.name = name;
        this.chemistry = chemistry;
        this.mathematics = mathematics;
        this.physics = physics;
        students.add(this);
    }

    public int getChemistry() {
        return chemistry;
    }

    public void setChemistry(int chemistry) {
        this.chemistry = chemistry;
    }

    public int getMathematics() {
        return mathematics;
    }

    public void setMathematics(int mathematics) {
        this.mathematics = mathematics;
    }

    public int getPhysics() {
        return physics;
    }

    public void setPhysics(int physics) {
        this.physics = physics;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void bestChem(){
        int x=-2;
        String y="";
        for (int j=0; j< students.size(); j++){
            if (students.get(j).getChemistry()>x) {
                x=students.get(j).getChemistry();
                y=students.get(j).getName();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Student(s) with the highest Chemistry grade among all students:" + y);
    }
    public void bestPhys(){
        int x=-2;
        String y="";
        for (int j=0; j< students.size(); j++){
            if (students.get(j).getPhysics()>x) {
                x=students.get(j).getPhysics();
                y=students.get(j).getName();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Student(s) with the highest Physics grade among all students:" + y);
    }
    public void bestMath(){
        int x=-2;
        String y="";
        for (int j=0; j<students.size(); j++){
            if (students.get(j).getMathematics()>x) {
                x=students.get(j).getMathematics();
                y=students.get(j).getName();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Student(s) with the highest Mathematics grade among all students:" + y);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `length()` method in ArrayList class (perhaps you meant `size()`). And please check other answers before answering to make sure that you do not duplicate any ideas or concepts.

Comment: You are correct, I'm gonna change that now. Thanks @Steyrix

Comment: I don't fully understand, could you please clarify me - if we call a method bestChem() with a single student, in this example - with darek.bestChem() - how  does the loop in this method can search among all students?

Comment: The ArrayList students is static that means it will remain the same regardless of which student it is currently in. More info on static fields: https://www.techopedia.com/definition/24033/static-field @stavla